# Remove invalid characters from value of json while creating JObject in USQL

Tags: c#, json, json.net, u-sql

In USQL I am reading csv file. It is telemetry data, so csv file may have any bad data. I am reading that csv file and creating JObject in USQL. I want to replace invalid characters from all values of json objects, so that my script will not fail because of bad data. I want to generate json output.

I am thinking to replace `"\\"` and `"\""` with blank before creating `JObject`. Please let me know whether this is correct way to remove bad data. If anyone has better solution, let me know. Also apart from "\" and "\"" do I need to remove any other characters.  My Usql code is mentioned below -

```
@Data=
SELECT new JObject(
                        new JProperty("Name", Name),                                                  
                        new JProperty("Description", Description)                      
                   ).ToString() AS Document
FROM @InputData;
```

Comment: personally, I would read the csv into a data table and then serialize the datatable into a json object.  By reading it into your datatable you can then validate each cell as you read it and use a regex to remove what you class as an illegal character .If you want a full code example I can make one for you shortly as I am not directly free right now.

Comment: I am mainly looking for USQL or C# solution

Comment: Can you provide some sample data sort of how it looks before and precisely how you want it to look after?

Comment: If Name has string "test\"ing", then using my code above it will give you parsing error. In that case I want to remove \" from that string which may cause issue. Like \" I want to know all other characters (invalid characters) which may case issue and replace them with blank.  Mainly I am looking into values of all columns ex. name and description bacause,  I have hard coded name of properties while creating JObject so name of properties will not have any issue. I just want to validate all values and correct them by replacing bad characters with blank.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. This will build up your DataTable and then using JSON.Net, this will serialize it all for you, you just need to build a regex expression to find and replace what you want to remove.

```
void Main()
{
    var dt = CSVtoDataTable(@"c:\temp\test.csv");

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        var str = row[col].ToString();
        row[col] = RegexReplace(str);
    }

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
}

public DataTable CSVtoDataTable(string filepath)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Temp");

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection($"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = {Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath)}; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\""))
    {
        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileName(filepath), conn);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
    return ds.Tables[0];

}

public string RegexReplace(string s)
{
    return Regex.Replace(s, @"\b[a-z]\w+", "*****");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes we can do like this, but wanted to know all bad characters which may cause issue while creating JObject. Ex. \" in "test\"ing" is bad character.

Comment: how is the system going to know what your bad characters are unless you use a regex to find them?